# Why is the magnetic field dot producted in the integral version of Ampere's circuital law?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

you know amperes circuital law? Well in that equation there's a dot product between the magnetic field B and a length element dl...why is that? I mean its not like the magnetic field can be at an angle to the length element. Its always parallel to the length element so $\cos(0)=1 $ which means the dot term is not needed in the equation

But yet it is there so I feel like I'm missing something fundamental or basic here...help would be great

Comment: Why do you think the magnetic field is parallel to the length element?

Comment: well... Can it not be parallel?....I mean magnetic field is circular , in other words its perpendicular to the raidus. But if the length element is not perpendicular to the radius it will not make a circle but some other shape. If it makes some other shape then the distance from the center of the wire to every dl element and to the magnetic field is not the same. Which would mean that the magnetic field is unconstant.

Comment: I think this is a fundamental misunderstanding: Ampère's circuital law actually applies to *any* closed loop that you can draw in 3D

Answer (score 1):

> I mean its not like the magnetic field can be at an angle to the length element. Its always parallel to the length element

This is not correct. The magnetic field certainly can be at an angle to the tangent line.

Consider a long straight wire carrying a steady current. If we take a circular path centered on the wire then, as you say, the field is always tangent to the path. Any other path will not have that property. Consider a square path around the wire, or a circular path outside the wire, or any other path. All of those will have places where the field is not tangent to the path.

The dot product is there to handle such paths.

Comment: but if we take a square as you said then the $B$ of the equation wouldn't be constant...It would be changing constantly

Comment: @alienare4442 so? The value of the magnetic field at each point along the curve is considered. Do you know what a line integral is?

Comment: @alienare4422 Yes. Ampere’s law applies to all electromagnetic fields, including non-constant ones

Answer (score 0):

Historical Note:
It was because back then scientists humored the idea that a 'magnetic charge' be taken along a path and we seek its total 'work done', similar to how we do it in Electrostatics. Although our thoughts are now more refined than back then, the theory is still meaningful and its manifestations are all the more useful.

Comment: How on earth does this answer the question?

Comment: how does it not? its motivation for OP's problem